# I want to click on a button who will mark 1 and if i click another time 11

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**i want to click on a button to mark "1" and if il click another times "11"**

```
function macrosun() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
var valeur_cel = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue;
if(valeur_cel = null){
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('1');
}
else{valeur_cel= valeur_cel ('*10+1');
}
}
```

Comment: Please answer my question its for a work.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
function macrosun() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const v = sh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  if (v == null) {
    sh.getRange('A1').setValue('1');
  }
  else {
    sh.getRange("A1").setValue((v * 10) + 1);
  }
}
```

#### = is an assignment operator not a comparison.